# Running Pace Calculator in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode6, calculator

I'm a complete newbie to Swift. I have created a running pace calculator as experiment in Playground and it works perfectly, but I struggle to figure out how to connect it to a UI.

Things in particular I struggle with currently:

- Casting a text string to an Int label
- Does the function that does the calculation go in the IBAction?

**Playground Code**

```
import UIKit

func PaceCalculator (minutes:Double, seconds:Double, distance:Double) -> Double{
    return ((minutes*60) + seconds) / distance
}

var paceInSeconds = PaceCalculator(28, 26, 10.1)
var paceInMinutes = paceInSeconds / 60
var roundedMinutes = Double(floor(paceInMinutes))
var decimalSeconds = paceInMinutes - roundedMinutes
var intPace = Int(floor(roundedMinutes))
var seconds = Int(floor(decimalSeconds * 60))

println("Your average pace is \(intPace):\(seconds)/km")
```

**Incomplete Swift Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    @IBAction func calculatePaceButton(sender: UIButton) {

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var minutesTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var paceLabel: UILabel!

}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Disclaimer:** I have no programming experience either. So be gentle on the jargon and explanation.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this will work for you :

You didn't added `secondsTextField` as `IBOutlet` please check that too.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var minutesTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var distanceTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var paceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var secondsTextField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func calculatePaceButton(sender: UIButton) {
        var paceInSeconds = PaceCalculator((minutesTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue, seconds: (secondsTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue, distance: (distanceTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue)
        var paceInMinutes = paceInSeconds / 60.0
        var roundedMinutes = Double(floor(paceInMinutes))
        var decimalSeconds = paceInMinutes - roundedMinutes
        var intPace = Int(floor(roundedMinutes))
        var seconds = Int(floor(decimalSeconds * 60))
        paceLabel.text = "\(intPace)"
    }

    func PaceCalculator (minutes:Double, seconds:Double, distance:Double) -> Double{
        return ((minutes*60) + seconds) / distance
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, perfect! Thanks Ashish.

Can you maybe explain what the piece below means? Especially the NSString and the .doubleValue.

minutesTextField.text as NSString).doubleValue

And yes, I picked up that I havent added the IBOutlet.)

Comment: in Swift 2 they directly allow to convert `Double(String)` but for general this syntax will work in all the versions. @SteynViljoen Hope it will help you

Comment: Thanks for your help! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here I would like to share my solution to calculate pace. The calculation is based on inputs of times and locations, which are more generic and useful.

```
typealias ShortFullTupleStrings = (short: String, full: String)
class PaceCalculator {
    private static func relatedTimeString(
      for value: TimeInterval)
      -> ShortFullTupleStrings?
    {
      let fm = DateComponentsFormatter()
      switch abs(value) {
      case 0 ..< 24*3600: // within one day
        fm.allowedUnits = [.year, .day, .hour, .minute, .second]
      case 24*3600 ..< 24*3600*10: // within 1-10 days
        fm.allowedUnits = [.year, .day, .hour, .minute]
      case 24*3600*10 ..< 24*3600*365: // within 10-365 days
        fm.allowedUnits = [.year, .day, .hour]
      default: // within 365-1000 days
        fm.allowedUnits = [.year, .day]
      }
      fm.unitsStyle = .short
      let short = fm.string(from: value)
      fm.unitsStyle = .full
      let full = fm.string(from: value)
      if let short = short, let full = full {
        return (short, full)
      } else {
        return nil
      }
    }

    static var isMetric: Bool {
      let locale = NSLocale.current
      let metricSystem = locale.usesMetricSystem
      return metricSystem
    }

    static func paceFrom( _
      dt1: Date, to dt2: Date,
      distanceFrom loc1: CLLocation, to loc2: CLLocation) -> 
    ShortFullTupleStrings?
    {
      let timeInterval = dt2.timeIntervalSince(dt1)
      let dist = loc2.distance(from: loc1)
      let pace: ShortFullTupleStrings?
      if !dist.isZero {
        let paceV: TimeInterval
        if isMetric {
            paceV = timeInterval / (dist / 1000.0)
        } else {
            paceV = timeInterval / (dist / 1609.344)
        }
        pace = relatedTimeString(for: paceV)
      } else {
        pace = nil
      }
      return pace
    }
}
```

`relatedTimeString` is a helper func to get a time string in the format of short form of # yrs, # days, # hrs, # min, # sec, and full form of # years, ..., depending on none zero values. For example, 6 min, 5 sec in short form, or 6 minutes, 5 seconds in full form.

In this way, the `func` is more generic and supports localization and accessibilities.